# Printer on different subnet, can I WiFi-broadcast it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

I have problem connecting laser (Brother HL-L2365DW) to my network.

If I connect it wirelessly to my router, which is quite far away, it can drop from WLAN and it's inaccessible. So I think it's best if I connect it with an Ethernet cable. But I can only connect the printer to the building's main domain (192.168.1), where it's assigned, via DHCP, the last part of IP. The wireless router that my devices use is also connected to this main domain and has its own subnet (192.168.10) and it doesn't list and WiFi-broadcast the printer, AirPrint doesn't work.

Can I somehow broadcast the printer via my secondary router, so that the appliances will see it?

Comment: have you tried setting the printer to a predictable IP (dhcp reservation), and connecting to it by IP address instead of attempting to discover it? Or perhaps putting your wifi router into AP mode, so your devices are on the same network as the printer and other devices?

Answer (score 0):

You're behind your own router for most devices by your description, broadcast based protocols dont tend to work across networks. Even if you statically assigned the printer an IP in your range, it wouldnt penetrate the WAN connection of a normal consumer router.

The simplest solution here is to integrate your private LAN with the rest of the building by turning your wireless router into an access point only(no DHCP, no firewall, no NAT). That way your wireless clients will get DHCP addresses in .1 as will the printer and they'll be able to bCast each other.